# SOQL to find all the recordTypes assigned to a profile or a user

Tags: soql, record-type, tasks

Need to show all the record types created on Task object assigned to the logged-in user.
I did not find any relation between the RecordType object and profile which can give me the details.

Tried querying record type object with different users of different profile but always getting all the available records types irrespective of record types assigned to the logged-in user.

How do get the assigned record types?

Comment: From what context?

Comment: No, I am looking for SOQL so that I can fire from an external service using REST.
The post has mentioned that via SOQL it is not possible :(